# Questions about IntelliJ Platform language plugin development

Tags: intellij-idea, grammar, intellij-plugin, bnf

I'm trying to add a support for `UnrealScript` language (OOP, with C-style syntax) for IntelliJ Idea according to [this](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html) tutorial. However, I'm having some difficulties with grammar and lexer generation.

Specifically, what's the purpose of :

- `extends(".*expr")=expr` in [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/testData/generator/ExprParser.bnf) .bnf file (line 5)?
- `name(".*expr")='expression'` in [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) sample.bnf file at the end of the article?

I'm adapting classical C syntax in the .bnf file so that once I have a working C-style grammar, I can tune it according to the aforementioned language. [Here](https://gist.github.com/arslancharyev31/c48d18d8f917ffe217a0e23eb3535957#file-c_v1-bnf) is what I've done so far. I'm adapting it from [this](https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm) page, which makes heavy use of left-recursion, which is unsupported by the generator. Therefore how can one convert, for instance, the following rule to non-recursive?

```
logical-or-expression ::= logical-and-expression
                      | logical-or-expression '||' logical-and-expression
```

What about this slightly more sophisticated one?

```
direct-abstract-declarator ::=  '(' abstract-declarator ')'
                           | {direct-abstract-declarator}? '[' {constant-expression}? ']'
                           | {direct-abstract-declarator}? '(' {parameter-type-list}? ')'
```

But apart from this, I feel an immense lack of theory of what I'm trying to accomplish, so more generally, **what are the theoretical prerequisites for adding language support in IntelliJ Platform**? So far, I've got myself acquainted only with general bnf/ebnf notation. Do I need to read the dragon book? If yes, then which chapters should I focus on (since I do not intend to write a compiler)?

Comment: Hello! Have you managed to implement US support? If yes, will you be willing to share your implementation?

Answer (score 4):

The `extends(".*expr")=expr` line changes how the AST classes are generated, making the AST more shallow, which in turn makes the PSI hierarchy nicer. Essentially, it means that any rules that match the regular expression `.*expr` will be treated as extending the `expr` rule, rather than being children.

This means that e.g. the types generated for `add_expr` or `mul_expr` would extend the `Expr` interface, so you'd be able to use `AddExpr` and `MulExpr` wherever you can use `Expr`. Without this, `Expr` would have getter methods for `AddExpr` and `MulExpr, etc. Check out [this section of the HOWTO](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/HOWTO.md#31-psi-basics).

The `name(".*expr")='expression'` line means that "<expression>" will be used to describe any rule that matches the regular expression. This is mostly surfaced in error messages - "<expression> expected, got XX". This is useful to group all expression rules together with a name, rather than list every variation.

Unfortunately, I can't give much advice on your other questions. GrammarKit does provide support some left recursion, as described in this [section on parsing expressions](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/HOWTO.md#24-compact-expression-parsing-with-priorities), but I don't really know details. Other than that, it is possible to rewrite left recursive rules, and it is best to search for examples of how to do this.

Similarly, I'd suggest looking for tutorials on writing parsers, and reading as much as possible. There is little written about how to write a parser for an IDE, but the big difference between writing a parser for a compiler and an IDE is error handling. An IDE needs to assume that your code is always broken (it usually is, when you're typing) and needs to recover gracefully. Similarly, the design of your AST is important, but there is no guidance available for this. It essentially boils down to your requirements - be prepared to tweak your grammar and AST structure to suit the features you're building.